# Magento 2 controller cached

Tags: magento2, magento-community, magento2.4.3, magento-connect, magento-commerce

I have created a redirect controller for the payment gateway for redirection to the payment method host but that controller is being cached when I enable the full page cache of Magento. If I remove full page cache then it is working fine.

Due to the controller being cached, the order total amount is showing the previous order's total on the payment gateway page.

Redirect Controller:-

```
<?php

namespace ST\Migs\Controller\Hosted;

class Redirect extends \ST\Migs\Controller\Hosted
{

    public function execute()
    {
        $incrementId = $this->_checkoutSession->getLastRealOrderId();
        if (!empty($incrementId)) {
            $order = $this->_getOrder();
            $response = $this->_view->getLayout()
                ->createBlock('ST\Migs\Block\Form\Hosted','st-form-hosted')
                ->setTemplate('ST_Migs::form/redirect.phtml')
                ->setFormUrl($this->_hosted->getFormUrl())
                ->setFormFields($this->_hosted->getFormFields($order))
                ->toHtml();
            $this->getResponse()->setBody($response);
        }

    }

}
```

Layout st_hosted_redirect.xml :-

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<layout xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/layout_generic.xsd">
    <container name="root">
        <block class="ST\Migs\Block\Form\Hosted" name="st-migs-from-hosted" template="ST_Migs::form/redirect.phtml" cacheable="false"/>
    </container>
</layout>
```

Is there any solution to disable the cache for this controller and block ?

I have tried adding following solution but none of them worked:-

a) add `$this->addData(array('cache_lifetime' => null));` in block constructor.

b) add `cacheable="false"` in layout for block.

c) add `'$page->setHeader('Cache-Control', 'no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate, max-age=0', true);'` in controller.

Please let me know if you solved the same problem.

Magento version 2.4.3-p3.

Comment: When you are redirecting, pass param with redirected url it will bypass from cache. try it I also did to resolve this issue.

Comment: @ZahidHussainMagento I didn't try this solution but I think it will work also.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Inside your execute function add this as the first line,

$this->resultPageFactory->create();

This method kicks off some code that loads the layout handles for the request. Then your layout xml will be used and the cache attribute of the blocks will be taken into account and full page caching will be correctly disabled.

Obviously make sure $this->resultPageFactory is included via the constructor and instantiated as \Magento\Framework\View\Result\PageFactory

Comment: Thanks Luke, It works like charm!

Comment: I have everything in place, but still, it's getting cached. Even though I've tried the methods from the question, nothing works for me. Basically, I am using a payment module from third-party gateway.